# Static noise which changes based on which usb port I've audio interface connected to?

Tags: noise, audio-processing

I've audio interface umc22. I thought I could hear some static noise Even with 0 gain. I recorded audio sample without any gain or even microphone attached. Yet there was still static white noise. I changed usb ports and it did result in different humming. I opened up Adobe audition and I can see that there too. What can be done?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked which other devices are using this troublesome USB port and how's the power usage situation (IIRC, max 500mA) (can be done through device manager) ?

Comment: I just tried on macbook, There was definitely noise there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got what you paid for. Behringer tends to be hit or miss: the designs are not terrible but quality control is all over the place and they do ship plenty of crappy units.

> What can be done?

1. Invest in a quality audio interface
2. Try to return yours for a different one.
3. Unplug the power supply and just run off the laptop battery (if it's a laptop)
4. Power manage your PC. Unplug as much connected devices as you can, and specifically USB powered devices. Look for "CPU hogs" and shut them down.
5. Try a different USB cable.

Comment: what interface would you recommend?

Comment: There are plenty of to choose from. Define needed features first and then budged. Web is full of shops selling audio interfaces. By following related discussion boards you get good info regarding possible issues with certain devices.